# IndexError: list index out of range when try to start range from 1

Tags: python, list

I have the following working code.

```
b=4
c=4
mylist = []
for s in range(b):
    mylist.append([])
    for g in range(c):
        mylist[s].append(0)       
print mylist
```

which gives the following output.

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However for my requirement I want to start the range from the first element. Hence I wrote the code as follows:

```
b=4
c=4
mylist = []
for s in range(1,b):
    mylist.append([])
    for g in range(1,c):
        mylist[s].append(0)       
print mylist
```

But this is giving me the error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand why. Please clarify if you know why.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you're trying to access the second element of a 1 element list. You're doing `[[]][1]`.

Comment: "I want to start the range from the first element": that's what you're doing, with zero-indexing. Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: It seems to me that you want to create a list containing zeroes, but want that list stating from index 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Lists are zero based, the first append always creates `l[0]`.  You need to fix your indices;

```
b=4
c=4
mylist = []
for s in range(1,b):
    mylist.append([])
    for g in range(1,c):
        mylist[s-1].append(0)   # have to subtract 1 to get back to zero-based index    
print mylist
```

your output then looks like this;

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for s in range(1,b):
    mylist.append([])
    for g in range(1,c):
        mylist[s].append(0)
```

In this loop, you're appending an empty list to `mylist`. `mylist` thusly only has one element in it, but within the second loop, you're trying to access `mylist[1]` when `s == 1`. This is why you're getting an Index Error.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As we know python list start from 0.
You can add a dummy object at index 0 to start from 1 then pop it at the end

Your code must be like this

```
 b=4
 c=4
 mylist = ['dummy']
     for s in range(1,b):
           mylist.append([])
           for g in range(1,c):
                 mylist[s].append(0) 
 mylist.pop(0)
 print mylist
```